# Creating a custom BigCommerce theme from scratch, without selling it in the theme store

Tags: bigcommerce

A client of mine wants to create their ecommerce site with BigCommerce as back-end. BigCommerce has lots of theme's available in their theme store. This client however does not want to be just another website using a certain theme, but have a theme unique to their company. You can build your own theme which would use your own config.php, something they use to set global variables in their templating engine.

However as far as I can read on their [developers site](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/) the only way that you could create your own theme is if you then start selling it in the theme store, which of course would allow other companies to adopt this same theme against a certain price. Something my client doesnt want. They want to be unique.

So my question is: Can you create a custom bigcommerce theme from scratch, without selling it in the theme store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question directly: No, you cannot create a theme from scratch without being a parter of bigcommerce and making your theme available in the theme store.

You can get close as @TheEks describes by simply choosing a theme (preferably the blueprint, available when going in to dev mode), and then overwriting whatever contents the html files have. You will need to check for updates to the bigcommerce theme yourself and implement those in your code. You will not be able to remove theme files, if you no longer use them, from the webdav server, only revert them to their original state. You can just ignore them of course.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, however you can set up a config.php file and all that. You can simply start with any theme available in the current theme store, download the HTML, CSS, JS, Image, etc files and customize them to your liking. These are completely open ended.

You won't really miss anything this way, the only thing the config file does is set the default store settings when that theme is applied such as menu depth, fly out menus, display of weight, etc. All that can be adjusted manually by you or your client in the store settings!